# ReSharper won't load when starting Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I started Visual Studio 2008 I got an error on the .Net Framework.
All my projects wouldn't load and there was een error with ReSharper 6 as well.
Which one I sadly don't remember.

After fixing the .Net Framework, I rebooted and all my projects loaded again.

However, my ReSharper 6 wasn't starting.
When I go to Tools -> Options -> ReSharper I see "An error occurred loading this property page." So Visual Studio knows it is installed.

I've tried removing and reinstalling ReSharper 6 but that didn't work.
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Most probably the error might have been that the Resharper trial period has expired. This happened to me many times.

Comment: It hasn't, I have a valid key provided to me by my company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you still have corrupt settings or not everything has been resolved when you "fixed the .NET framework"

If you can get to the ReSharper options, it might be worth clearing the Cache (General tab - Clear caches)

You can also access ReSharper options via Tools -> Options -> ReSharper instead of the ReSharper menu, you have the option in here too to Suspend it.

if not;

Try resetting to the default settings

```
 devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

You could also run it up in safe mode first, although since this will disable ReSharper it's unlikely to prove anything

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

Failing that, an uninstall of ReSharper first, Then VS - then a re-install of both in the opposite order would be my only other advice.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I found a different option:
devenv.exe -ResetSkipPkgs, that one worked

Comment: I was going nuts and `-ResetSkipPkgs` did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I've used

```
devenv.exe -ResetSkipPkgs
```

This allows to show errors.
Using

```
devenv.exe /log
```

Error was logged at

```
<USER FOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

So I've discovered

```
Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID
'JetBrains.ReSharper' is already loaded at C:\Program Files x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.1\Bin\...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.0\

CreateInstance failed for package
[JetBrains.ReSharper.Product.VisualStudio.v10.0.Package, Version=8.0.14.856,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325]
```

It was a gone wrong installation of ReSharper version 8.0.
I removed this folder using Administration privs:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.0\
```

My 2 cents

Nico D.

Answer (score 1):

I had a some what different issue, but I thought it was worth sharing. I installed Resharper 9, but my Visual Studios still thought I had some older version of Resharper installed. If you go to **Tools** then **Options**, you may see **Resharper** and **Resharper Ultimate**. I had to find the [old version](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-) of Resharper my Visual Studios thought I still had installed. Specific instructions:

1. Close Visual Studios
2. Download and install [old Resharper](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-)
3. Uninstall old Resharper
4. Open Visual Studios, then close it (for some reason, it wouldn't work for me unless I did this step in between)
5. Install [new Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)
6. Open Visual Studios